# Best approach to showing multiple html without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a "server" that serves up individual html pages for each associated item in the server.  I've done a lot of looking around but I'm afraid I just don't know enough to ask the right question.  How I'd like it to work is as follows:

Static Sidebar (boostrap simple-sidebar)
Ordered list of links to associated html docs
When the associated link is pressed to display that content in my main container field.

From what I've read some use iframe in the main html container and make the clicked link the active link. 
Others use bootstrap modal, but modals no longer support remote content.

Any hints toward how to ask the right question would be great!

Comment: As I see you have 2 options, the first is use a iFrame as yourself said, the second is to use AJAX, using AJAX don't need to be modal, you can do an http request and update the content of the content. The main problem with both approachs is the URL, to solve this you can use the # techinique or the history API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). Would be nice to have an javascript parse the URL on page load to load the content that the URL is point to, if using this approach. Frameworks like amber and angular have routers to do that.

Comment: few people use iframes for single page applications, ajax is the norm and typically done without modals. no idea whare idea that modals don't support remote content comes from though

Comment: "This option is deprecated since v3.3.0 and will be removed in v4. "

Comment: per the documentation the modal will work once then not again.  console complains that loading remote content is not great for user experience and hence has been removed.